# Javascript object string/quotes issue

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
var selectdata = {
     "tablename": "dbo.vw_bla",
     "where": "ID_Prod like @idprod",
     "whereparameters": [{
         "name": "idprod",
         "value": ' +  $(prodvariable) + ',
         "type": "varchar"
     }],
     "orderby": "ID_Prod ASC"
 };
```

`prodvariable` is a variable in which a have stored a number. For example `6`.

This should be passed as `6`.

I have tried several combinations of quotes, escapes, +, etc but I cannot figure out the right way.

Comment: Is it a js variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any quotes for `prodvariable`. Use that variable directly in the value:

```js
var prodvariable = '6';
var selectdata = {"tablename":"dbo.vw_bla", 
                  "where":"ID_Prod like @idprod",
                  "whereparameters": [
                  {"name": "idprod", 
                  "value":  prodvariable , 
                  "type":"varchar"}],
                  "orderby":"ID_Prod ASC"};
console.log(selectdata);
```

Comment: @hacking_mike glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the value of the `prodvariable` variable but surrounded with double quotes? You can do so using ES2015 string template literals:

```
{ "value":  `"${prodvariable}"` }
```

Then `value` will be `"6"` in your case.

You can achieve the same result with simple string concatenation as well:

```
{ "value":  '"' + prodvariable + '"' }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the prodvariable as number try like below

```
var prodvariable = 6
var selectdata = {
     "tablename": "dbo.vw_bla",
     "where": "ID_Prod like @idprod",
     "whereparameters": [{
         "name": "idprod",
         "value": prodvariable,
         "type": "varchar"
     }],
     "orderby": "ID_Prod ASC"
 };
```

If you want to pass the variable as string try like below

```
var prodvariable = 6
var selectdata = {
     "tablename": "dbo.vw_bla",
     "where": "ID_Prod like @idprod",
     "whereparameters": [{
         "name": "idprod",
         "value": `${prodvariable}`, 
         "type": "varchar"
     }],
     "orderby": "ID_Prod ASC"
 };
```

**You could do one of the following method to pass prodvariable to json object.**

> "value": prodvariable // this will be passed as number if prodvariable
>   is number
>
> "value": `${prodvariable}`,
>
> OR
>
> "value": '"'+ prodvariable + '"',